# Trying to install centos 7 -- getting pane is dead error

Tags: centos

This is my very first installation of any Linux distribution. I have seen "pane is dead" questions and answers to them here, but I don't think they apply to me -- for one thing, I'm not using Kickstart (whatever it is). Also no virtual machine, no Parallels, etc... This is a clean install on a just bought disk (on a newly bought computer, really).

Here's what I did.

I downloaded 7.6.1810 DVD-ISO version from one of the mirrors given on the official CentOS site. Burned it to an USB stick using dd under Linux Mint. I made sure I burned it to USB as a whole (/dev/sdz), not to a partition (/dev/sdz1).

Now I plug the stick into the new computer. It is recognized and I'm greeted by "Install CentOS 7" screen. I choose "install", lines start running, most of which are ok-ed. Two lines are not ok-ed:

[ INFO ] dev-virtio\x2dports-com.redhat.spice.0.device is not active.

[ DEPEND ] Dependency failed for Activation socket for spice guest agent daemon.

Nevertheless, this run of lines successfully ends, after which I get "Starting installer, one moment..." and very quickly after that "Pane is dead".

When I alt-tab to log, I get the message saying something to the effect that log-file can't be found. And that's it.

Any ideas?

GPU is Nvidia 2080.

USB stick is 6 months old. I've used it successfully as a boot drive for Win 10. Today I formatted it and burned with centos using dd. Now when I plug it into a win-computer, windows doesn't recognize it -- it's not on the list of discs. If I go to disk management, it's there, it has one 9 mb partition called "Anaconda" and 14.59 gbs' worth of unallocated disk space (it's a 16 gb stick).

EDIT: Turned out it was the dying USB stick.

Comment: Those two "not ok" lines occur if you are not booting in a KVM virtual machine. You can ignore them if you are trying to boot on anything else (like a physical computer). Your issue basically has two likely causes: Your USB is corrupt, or CentOS doesn't like your video card. You didn't mention what video card you have, though.

Comment: @MichaelHampton GPU is Nvidia 2080. USB stick is 6 months old. I've used it successfully as a boot drive for Win 10. Today I formatted it and burned with centos using dd. Now when I plug it into a win-computer, windows doesn't recognize it -- it's not on the list of discs. Could this mean that it's dead? Or dd just did something to it that makes it windows-inaccessible?

Comment: windows won't read any linux like partitions without specific tools, so your USB stick is currently linux-only ; when you will need it again with windows you will have to partition & format it as FAT or any other windows world format.

Comment: 1) Did you verify the checksum of the CentOS ISO? Go to a mirror and download the sha256sum.txt file and compare  the value within to the checksum of the ISO. 2) Suggest once verified you remake the LiveUSB with http://Rufus.IE 3) Repeat using an Ubuntu distro http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ubuntu-releases/18.04/  to see if this is CentOS specific. 4) Once you've done 1)-3), click [edit[ to add the results to your original question; do not click on Add Comment, use [edit] instead.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that you do dd with bs=4M since a lot of USB drives cannot correctly handle very small blocksizes (dunno why, just experience).

You can also try text-based installer:

When you see install centos menu option press the tab key, add text to the end of any existing installer command line arguments and then press the return key.